# Autosize an SELECT left of a static length INPUT field

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to auto size an SELECT left of an fixed length INPUT (number). Like so: [image: example]

I got this result using a horrible width=83% on the select and width=3em on the input. This is totally not *responsive* of course. Problem is that when I say width=auto, it will resize to the length of the contents of the drop down box, instead of the available size in the grid it's in.

Thus: How to autosize an SELECT to make use of available **remaining** space?

Context:

```
<div class="col-4">
<select name="class" style="width:83%; vertical-align:top;">
      <option value=""></option>    
      <option value="11" selected>Warlock</option>
</select>
<input style="width: 3em; vertical-align:top; text-align: center;" type="number" step=1 min=1 max=20 name="class_level" value="8">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use calc :

```
select { width: calc(100% - 3em); }
```

Add some margin in the calc if you want.

Comment: thanks! hadn't imagined the answer was going to be this simple :'D